# EntityFramework Best Practices RE: Database Security

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1

I have a situation where I want to use permissions on database objects, but not allow users who are smart enough to make connections through excel and access to manipulate data.  We want to require a user to make a connection through our Web Application this ensures validation of data in one place.  Is there a way to ensure that when a user makes a connection to the database and has the permission set that allows him to Insert, Update, or Delete that he is doing in through the Web Application?

If there is not A way, then what are your opinions on dealing with this situation without using a master user for the web application connection?

Comment: Don't give your users access to the database.  Have a single database login for the website.

Comment: Please read the last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use master account which is what most system does because there is no reason to give user access to database if you want to use another tier (your web application) for data validation, rules checking, etc. That is a way to not allow user accessing database directly.

Once you give user access to database he can do whatever his permission allows him. There will be nothing which will stop user from accessing the database directly. Moreover if you don't use master account in web application you will have to delegate user through the web application (it requires windows domain and Kerberos if database server doesn't sit on the same machine as web application). This delegation will give your user exactly same permissions in your application as the user have without your application.

Comment: I know this is NOT the most correct way when dealing with DbContext, but because of an MOA between my customer and their customers, can I utilize `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` in order to send an entity to the database allowing for the use of StoreProcedures to reduce the risk of a user being able to Insert, Update, or Delete?

Comment: But what account will be used for connection to database from your application? If application master account you can use what ever you want. If user account, you will still not solve the main problem. User will must have permission to execute every single stored procedure and select data (otherwise you cannot use LINQ queries) and will be able to do that without your application. So generally to ensure all validations you must move all your logic and validation to stored procedures.

Comment: Yes you are correct, permissions will be given to users directly on the Database tier.  My solution would be that since the stored procedures have a name and parameters that won't be public, that means it is more likely that the user will not be able to perform the Insert, Update, or Delete functions because the app is an intranet app, so all users are internal.  The only other option I have found is to perform a logon trigger, but the amount of extra transactions that have to take place for that doesn't out weigh the risk.

Comment: If you have access to database stored procedures and their parameters are always public. You can get this information from system views for all object you have permissions to use. Simply use single master account for your web application and don't give your users direct access rights to database.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx